# ExtJS & Css Panel Background's

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I am new to both Sencha ExtJS and Css as a whole. Basically I have a 3 child panel's inside a master panel. I want to set the same background color to just three panel's inside the master panel using CSS. I have created a .css file and linked it into the HTML. The content of the CSS file are:

```
.x-panel.child-content-style {
background-image : url('TitleBackground.png');
```

}

I can make this happen without using css by setting the `bodyStyle:{"background-image":"url('TitleBackground.png')"}` config. It works perfectly but I feel there is probably a better way to do it using css.

When I try and add my css using the cls config property nothing happens. When set the bodyCls property it then sets the backgrond of the entire application which is not what I want. I am looking to change the background to only a few panel's. I have also tried specifying the css element name in the bodyStyle config in lieu of the inline with no joy.

Here are my child panel's:

```
{ xtype: 'panel', html: '<img src=\'appIcon.png\' style=\'width:52px;height:52px\'> &nbsp;', cls: 'child-content-style' },
                    { xtype: 'panel', html: '<h2 style=\'font-family:verdana\'>Toolkit v3.0</h2>', bodyStyle:{"background-image":"url('TitleBackground.png')"} },
                    { xtype: 'panel', html: '&nbsp;<img src=\'appIcon.png\' style=\'width:52px;height:52px\'>', bodyStyle:{"background-image":"url('TitleBackground.png')"} }
```

Is this even possible to do or should I just cjoke it up to a loss and leave it inline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is [`bodyCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bodyCls) what you are looking for.

Comment: Worked like a champ. I have tried reading the Sencha documentation but I am still confused regarding the difference between the cls, bodyCls and bodyStyle configs are. Could you provide an explanation for someone who is new to Sencha and Css?